# https for a subdomain certificate type

Tags: https, subdomain

Im  currently developing a client section  for  our private webinterface.
I would like to use https  but the  server is not registered to a domain.

My research has shown that  using  a valid https certificate for a ip address is not possible  or at least quite complicated.

The other  option  would be  to use  a sub domain
something like  remote.example.com which would point to  my servers ip address.

My question is  can this be done with a standard certificate ?  Can I just  use  remote.example.com  as  a domain  name?

Answer (score 0):

Ok  it works with a standard  certficate  just set   the   CN to  remote.example.com